# Ajax/JQuery: Can't read the data returned (undefined)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to log the JSON data returned in the code below and it always returns as undefined in the console.

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"campcpcedit.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{platform:platform, btnid:btnid, newcpc:newcpc},
    success:function(data){
      if (data.success) {
            myAlertTop();
            changeBid(_btn);
        }
        else {
            myAlertBottom();
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    }
  });
```

The JSON response is this:

```
{"success":false,"message":"Error"}
```

The code to generate it in campcpcedit.php:

```
  if($conn->query($upquery) === TRUE && $apiSuccess == "1") {
      echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
  }
  else{
      echo "Error: " . $upquery . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 
                             'message' => "Error")
                 );
        }
```

The if (data.success) is working as the 2 functions myAlertTop() and myAlertBottom() are firing properly. 
I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're sending the error first, so it's not valid JSON. Why not add the error as another array item instead?

Comment: I removed 'success' => false and changed the log to console.log(data.message) but I still get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised to hear that the solution was to use the following...

```
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(data).message);
```

I believe the reason it is failing is because your PHP is returning the following example string back to the client, which the client can't convert to an object (which the `$.ajax` will try and do by default).

```
Error: XXX<br>xxx{"success":false,"message":"Error"}
```

```js
var jsonReturn = 'Error: XXX<br/>xxx{"success":false,"message":"Error"}';
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(jsonReturn).message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead, what I suggest is that you remove the first `echo` from your PHP, and instead add a new item to your array...

```
// echo "Error: " . $upquery . "<br>" . $conn->error;
echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 
                       'message' => "Error",
                       'error' => $upquery . "<br>" . $conn->error));
```

That should result in a properly formed JSON string which can be parsed, meaning that the `data` variable in `success:function(data)` is the object you're expecting...

```
{"success":false,"message":"Error","error":"XXX<br>xxx"}
```

```js
var jsonReturn = '{"success":false,"message":"Error","error":"XXX<br/>xxx"}';
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(jsonReturn).message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have to parse the JSON response.

```
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(data).message);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had limited time last evening. Are you sure this is the solution?  My original comment was trying to point out that your PHP code is returning `Error: XXX<br/>xxx{"success":false,"message":"Error"}`.  I'm surprised that running a parse on that is working

Comment: You are right. My problem was indeed the JSON response was bound to another echo in my PHP which resulted in a malformed JSON. I had another problem yet because I wasn't parsing the JSON  by using  `dataType: 'json'` in my Ajax I still had to parse it on my side.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  Another option (instead of the `dataType:'json'`) is to set the content type in the PHP... that would result in `$.ajax` automatically detecting it's JSON and converting it for you.  Before the first `echo` put... `header('Content-Type: application/json');`